# android datepicker error datepicker does't popup at all and can't choose date

Tags: android, android-datepicker

```
public void registerButtonListener() {
    mData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(2);
            // showDatePicker();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case 2:
            return showTimePicker();
    }   
//return super.onCreateDialog(id);
return dialog;

} //kraj na dialogot

private TimePickerDialog showTimePicker() {
    TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(
        this, 
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            // @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
                updateTimeButtonText();
            }
        },
        mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),true);
    return timePicker;
}
```

I don't get any picker and I have used this code from a tutorial in another example and it works. What's my error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't initiated the calendar, in your case put in `onCreate()` `mCalendar=Calendar.getInstance()`, and that will probably fix your error.